# Missing values in lmFit [limma R package]

Tags: r, bioinformatics, linear-regression, bioconductor

[This question is specific to bioinformatics. There are posts elsewhere but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.]

If I have a gene/protein expression data with missing values (`NA`), how does `lmFit` of the `limma` package handle these values? Note that the missing values are not in the design matrix, but rather, in the data matrix only.

Here is a simulated, working example that illustrates my question:

```
library(limma)
my_genes <- matrix(rnorm(9000, -10, 10), ncol=4)
my_genes <- as.data.frame(my_genes)
rownames(my_genes) <- paste("Gene", 1:nrow(my_genes))
## Randomly introducing NAs
purrr::map_df(my_genes, function(x) {x[sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.95, 0.05), size = length(x), replace = TRUE)]})
tx <- 1:2 #suppose treatment is columns 1 & 2
ctrls <- 3:4 #suppose controls is columns 3 & 4
my_design <- model.matrix( ~factor(c(1,1,0,0)))
my_design
fit <- lmFit(my_genes, my_design)
fit <- eBayes(fit)
plot(fit$logFC, -log10(fit$p.value))
```

If you find any websites / posts that can help, feel free to share with a post or comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post in CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-does-r-handle-missing-values-in-lm) answers my own question in detail. In short, the way of how `lmFit` deals with missing values is similar to how `lm` does. Rows with missing values are subjected to `na.exclude`, or "case-wise deletion."

Alternatively: Though it's not an ideal solution, it might be appropriate to just impute the missing gene-expression values. For example, using the `knn.impute` function in the `impute` Bioconductor package.